# Resin configure can't find openssl on mac

Tags: macos, web-applications, application-server, resin

Can't find OpenSSL during the installation of Resin 4.0.64 on command `./configure`.

Log:

```
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin19.4.0
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin19.4.0
checking target system type... x86_64-apple-darwin19.4.0
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... automake/install-sh -c -d
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of gcc... none
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for fgrep... /usr/bin/grep -F
checking how to print strings... printf
checking for ld used by gcc... /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... no
checking for egrep... (cached) /usr/bin/grep -E
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking sys/poll.h usability... yes
checking sys/poll.h presence... yes
checking for sys/poll.h... yes
checking sys/epoll.h usability... no
checking sys/epoll.h presence... no
checking for sys/epoll.h... no
checking for JAVA_HOME... /Users/username/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-14/Contents/Home
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 196608
checking how to convert x86_64-apple-darwin19.4.0 file names to x86_64-apple-darwin19.4.0 format... func_convert_file_noop
checking how to convert x86_64-apple-darwin19.4.0 file names to toolchain format... func_convert_file_noop
checking for /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for objdump... objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for dlltool... no
checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... printf %s\n
checking for ar... ar
checking for archiver @FILE support... no
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from gcc object... ok
checking for sysroot... no
checking for a working dd... /bin/dd
checking how to truncate binary pipes... /bin/dd bs=4096 count=1
checking for mt... no
checking if : is a manifest tool... no
checking for dsymutil... dsymutil
checking for nmedit... nmedit
checking for lipo... lipo
checking for otool... otool
checking for otool64... no
checking for -single_module linker flag... yes
checking for -exported_symbols_list linker flag... yes
checking for -force_load linker flag... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... yes
checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -fno-common -DPIC
checking if gcc PIC flag -fno-common -DPIC works... yes
checking if gcc static flag -static works... no
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the gcc linker (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... darwin19.4.0 dyld
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... yes
./configure: line 12674: test: too many arguments
checking if /usr/bin/java is 64-bit... 
no
./configure: line 13290: plugin_ld_shlib: command not found
checking if /bin/cp accepts -u... 
no
checking for JNI in /Users/username/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-14/Contents/Home/include/darwin ... found
Using JVMTI for class reloading
Can't find OpenSSL include ''
conftest.c:1:10: fatal error: 'openssl/ssl.h' file not found
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
configure: WARNING: Can't compile SSL.  Check compilation flags: gcc  -g -O2 -D_POSIX_PTHREAD_SEMANTICS -DHAS_SOCK_TIMEOUT -DHAS_JVMTI  -L  -lssl -lcrypto 
checking that generated files are newer than configure... done
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating modules/c/src/Makefile
config.status: creating modules/c/src/common/Makefile
config.status: creating modules/c/src/apache2/Makefile
config.status: creating modules/c/src/resin_os/Makefile
config.status: creating init.d/resin
config.status: creating bin/resinctl
config.status: executing depfiles commands
config.status: executing libtool commands


Resin Configuration Summary:

  RESIN       : 4.0.64
    home      : /usr/local/share/resin-4.0.64
    root      : /var/resin
    conf      : /etc/resin
    log       : /var/log/resin
    plugins   : common resin_os 

  JAVA_HOME   : /Users/username/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-14/Contents/Home

  JNI         : 32-bit
    include       : -I/Users/username/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-14/Contents/Home/include -I/Users/username/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-14/Contents/Home/include/darwin
    CFLAGS        : 
    cflags_shlib  : -DSHARED_MODULE
    ld_shlib      : gcc
    ldflags_shlib : -dynamiclib -undefined suppress -flat_namespace
    libs_shlib    : 
    select() for keepalives

  OPENSSL     : No OpenSSL has been found
    *** OpenSSL libraries cannot be compiled ***
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run:
`./configure --with-openssl=/usr/local/opt/openssl`

**Source:**
https://github.com/vysheng/tg/issues/1488